# Matplotlib - add titles to the legend rows

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I created a legend which contains two rows, as below:

[image]

Is it possible to add a label/title to each row, that when I show the plot the legend appears as:

```
Title1: One One One
Title2: Two Two Two
```

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no built-in option to set row titles in legends.
As a workaround you may preprend a first column to the legend, which has no handles, but only labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.exp(-np.arange(5))

markers=["s", "o", ""]
labels =["one", "two"]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(6):
    ax.plot(y*i+i/2., marker=markers[i//2], label=labels[i%2])

h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ph = [plt.plot([],marker="", ls="")[0]]*2
handles = ph + h
labels = ["Title 1:", "Title 2:"] + l
plt.legend(handles, labels, ncol=4)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The main drawback here is that there is a lot of whitespace at the positions where the handles of the row titles would sit.

Setting `markerfirst=False` would make this less apparent:

[image]

If all of those are not an option one needs to dive a little deeper into the legend. The legend consists of `Packer` objects. It is then possible to identify those two packers from the first column that take up the space and set their width to zero

```
leg = plt.legend(handles, labels, ncol=4)

for vpack in leg._legend_handle_box.get_children()[:1]:
    for hpack in vpack.get_children():
        hpack.get_children()[0].set_width(0)
```

This should now pretty much give the desired row titles

[image]

---

The equivalent thing for **column titles** can be achieved by swapping the `[:1]` like this:

```py
handles = ph[:1] + h[::2] + ph[1:] + h[1::2]
labels = ["Title 1:"] + l[::2] + ["Title 2:"] + l[1::2]
leg = plt.legend(handles, labels, ncol=2)

for vpack in leg._legend_handle_box.get_children():
    for hpack in vpack.get_children()[:1]:
        hpack.get_children()[0].set_width(0)
```

[image: matplotlib legend column titles]

Comment: I just remembered an [older post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021593/how-can-i-export-legend-markers-from-matplotlib-one-at-a-time) of mine, which brought me to an acceptable solution. I updated the answer with what should now give you the desired row titles.

Comment: Thanks a lot, nice explanation and worked very well!