# matplotlib legend title on single row with legend labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using a legend title (via matplotlib), which places the title above the legend entries, however I want to create a long thin legend under the plot.  `ncol` will create a single row of legend entries, however I do not know how to get the legend title on the on the same row.

MWE

```
import numpy as np

%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

X1 = np.random.rand(50)
X2 = np.random.rand(50)
Y = np.random.rand(50)

plt.plot(X1,Y,X2,Y)
plt.legend(labels = ['X1','X2'],ncol=2,title='legend title:',loc=3)
```

I would like the legend to look like

> legend title: ----- X1  ----- X2

instead of

> legend title:
>   ----- X1  ----- X2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a code -

```
labels =["X1", "X2"]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
val = [X1, X2]
for i in range(2):
    ax.plot(val[i], Y, label=labels[i]) # Plotting one at a time
h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels() # Extracting handles and labels
ph = [plt.plot([],marker="", ls="")[0]] # Canvas
handles = ph + h
labels = ["legend title:"] + l  # Merging labels
plt.legend(handles, labels, ncol=3)
plt.show()
```

[image: plt]

For more info, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44072076/10734525)